# Addition in Java using Notepad

Tags: java, calculator, addition

```
class Addition
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    int x, y, z;
    System.out.printIn("Enter two integers to calculate their sum");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = in.nextInt();
    y = in.nextInt();
    z = x + y;
    System.out.printIn("Sum of enetered Integers="+z);
   }
}
```

I saw this somewhere and I can't somehow understand the purpose of
**Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);** in the code, can someone explain it?
It would be appriciated

Comment: `Scanner` is an object to *scan* from the system input stream (in your example)! Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more details.

Comment: Did you try reading the javadoc for Scanner?  It provides a helpful example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.  (Note in particular footnote #1.)

Comment: Okay thanks , I'll read it

Comment: Scanner class used to get the user input values .Here in above used they have two input for sum ie x,y .

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System in=new Scanner()` creates a Scanner object that helps you read from input streams, files... The System.in argument tells the **in** object to read from the default input stream, which usually is your keyboard. 
If you want to read from a text file, you should create a file object with the file path as an argument, and pass the file object as an argument to the **Scanner** object. Something like this `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));`